# MQTT: cannot subsribe to the topic in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mqtt

Im trying to read a data from localhost mqtt broker. For that purpose i am using following code:

```
    m_client = new QMqttClient(this);
    m_client->setHostname("127.0.0.1");
    m_client->setPort(1883);
    m_client->connectToHost();
    connect(m_client,&QMqttClient::connected,this,&mqtt::isConnected);//um zu sehen, ob man verbundet hat
    topic.setFilter("test");
    auto subscription = m_client->subscribe(topic, qos0);
    if(!subscription){
       qDebug()<<"Could not subscribe. Is there a valid connection?";
        return 0;
    }
    connect(m_sub, &QMqttSubscription::messageReceived, this, &mqtt::updateMessage);
    return 1;
```

however, when I check, whether subscription succeeded or not:

```
if(!subscription){
       qDebug()<<"Could not subscribe. Is there a valid connection?";
        return 0;
    }
```

I always see the message, that I am not subscribed. Notwithstanding that, I am successfully connecting to the localhost, so I see it on the console output (last line) :

```
Could not subscribe. Is there a valid connection?
qml: cannot connect
client is connected
```

I am wondering that `client is connected` comes as the last one, although there is no threads to make the code run asynchronously.      Theoretically the code must wait, 'till it connects to the broker and then run the rest, but as far as i understood it myself - it doesn't wait for the connection and goes further, so that it doesn't know - where it has to subscribe? Any thoughts?

---

Edit:  I have forgotten to include `isConnected` method:

```
void mqtt::isConnected()
{
    qDebug()<<"client is connected";
}
```

Comment: Try to subscribe in the isConnected method.

Comment: @eyllanesc unfortunately it's not included in `QMqttClient`. What you recommeding is prbbly from Tcp-Class.

Comment: mmm I do not understand you. use  `void mqtt::isConnected(){   topic.setFilter("test");
    auto subscription = m_client->subscribe(topic, qos0); qDebug() << subscription }`

Comment: @eyllanesc I mean, there is no `isConnected` method available. For that purpose I need to use another class, other from `QMqttClient`

Comment: How is it not available? If you are using it in the connection: `connect(m_client,&QMqttClient::connected,this,&mqtt::isConnected);`, what is `isConnected` in this connection? please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc im so sorry man, i was confused with it. So I've edited the question and ur meaning that I need to subscribe to the topic inside the `isConnected` method? Hmm, it makes sense.

Comment: Exactly, if there is no connection then there is no way to verify if you can subscribe or not.

Comment: @eyllanesc well thank you man, it works! Mb you could also help me, how can I properly see the output?  I did the `connect` to see update for messages, but I see nothing :((

Comment: That is another problem so you have to create a post detailing the problem, in addition to providing an MRE

Comment: @eyllanesc ok i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription must be given after the connection, so you must invoke subscribe in the isConnected method:

```cpp
void mqtt::isConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "client is connected";
    topic.setFilter("test");     
    auto subscription = m_client->subscribe(topic, qos0); 
    qDebug() << subscription
}
```